# Where is my neutral bar?

Tags: electrical-panel

[image: my panel]

Hi, I need to add a 30 amp double pole breaker to my full 100 amp QO breakers panel.

I am planning on getting two tandem breakers, that I can place in the bottom part of my panel.

Now for the 30 amp circuit, where do I connect the neutral and ground ?
Seems like its the top part that are ground buses? I am very confused with the present wiring.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is this fed from the meter or from a breaker between the meter and this location? The hot feeder on the right-hand side is *rather exposed* to be poking around in this panel unless it can be shut off upstream. That will be live and unfused even when the panel is shut off, if fed from the meter directly. Not the best place to risk a mistake... The left is also somewhat exposed.

Comment: I strongly support and encourage people to DIY and learn. I'd also _VERY STRONGLY_ encourage _you_ to do a _lot_ more learning before you embark on this endeavor. Knowing where the neutral bus bar is in a panel is a fairly basic knowledge step. You are, obviously, asking good questions before you start, please for your health, and the safety of our house, continue to ask more questions _before_ you start the work! I'd suggest laying out your full installation plan with all details in a new question here and asking for confirmation that you're on the right track.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes I am being cautious and I appreciate you stressed it so I am even more extra cautious. Yes this is the main panel connected to meter and I don't have any abilities to shut down the power to the lugs.

Comment: Then it's much like reaching into a box with a couple of cobras...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your neutral is the large white wire going into the middle of the top bus bar. It appears that the three bus bars are all connected together and there are neutral wires going to each bar. There is also a ground wire coming up from the bottom of the panel that is connected to the second bus bar. This appears to be a main panel where neutrals and grounds can/are connected to the same bus bars. You can connect your neutral and ground wires to any of the three bus bars at the top of the main breakers.

As @Ecnerwal mentioned in his comment, you have some dangerously exposed hot wires connecting to your main breaker especially since you'll be running wires up there and connecting them to the bus bars. You should correct this. There also appears to be a cable entering the box on the left side that doesn't have the proper connector securing it to the box. Fix that too.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me!

Answer (score 1):

Notice the panel has a steel box (enclosure).

Look closely at the construction of the bar(s) in question.  If the bar is on insulated standoffs to isolate it from the chassis, then it is designed to be a neutral bar. Only such bars can be used for neutral.

Bars which are directly bolted to panel chassis, and could not be isolated, are ground bars only.

In a main panel (first disconnect past the meter), grounds are *allowed* on the neutral bar. But they can also be on ground bars.

So if you are in a main panel and find yourself short on neutral spaces (they always give you enough), move some grounds to a ground bar. They can be bought as accessories, check your panel label for the specific model numbers that will fit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, also helped me